Is there a more programatic approach to implementing the `Display` trait for an enum?
Currently, I am implementing the Display trait for enums like so:
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Thing {
    SomeThing,
    AnotherThing,
}

impl Display for Thing {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Thing::SomeThing => write!(f, "SOME_THING"),
            Thing::AnotherThing => write!(f, "ANOTHER_THING"),
        }
    }
}

This seems tedious and repetitive. Is there a different way? Considering that there's a predictable pattern.
I tried the following until I realised the obvious mistake in this approach:
impl Display for TokenType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let thing = self.to_string();
        let thing_split: Vec<&str> = thing.split("/(?=[A-Z])/").collect();
        write!(f, "{}_{}", thing_split[0].to_uppercase(), thing_split[1].to_uppercase())
    }
}

The to_string method becomes accessible after implementing the Display trait:

This trait is automatically implemented for any type which implements the Display trait. As such, ToString shouldn’t be implemented directly: Display should be implemented instead, and you get the ToString implementation for free.


You can use strum for these purposes.

Since you derive Debug anyway, you could use it:
impl Display for Thing {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result  {
         write!(f,"{:?}",*self)
    }
}


The output of Debug must not be relied on for any functionality of the program. There are no guarantees on what Debug will produce, and it is possible on nightly to remove Debug support entirely when compiling a program.

@KevinReid: That is not fully correct. The implementation can change in future version, but the Debug  won't be removed. I had the impression, the OP doesn't need any special implementation or outpout. In the latter case, of course, a macro would be better.

If OP really does not need the output to be in some special form, implementing Display is the wrong step. They should stay with Debug only.

I want the output to be formatted in all upper case and separated by underscores like so: "SOME_WORD"
